# React Native ImageBackground width auto grows with content inside

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a horizontal flatlist with image banners. The problem is width grows with text inside. I want the image width to be fixed. Please suggest me the efficient way to handle this. I will share my code below.

```
const carData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bgImage: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
    headerText: 'Did you know',
    discountVal: '20%',
    bodyText:
      'Of power was generated via Bettrbarista clean energy initiative from compostable serveware to reusables.',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bgImage: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
    headerText: 'Did you know',
    discountVal: '20%',
    bodyText:
      'Of power was generated via Bettrbarista clean energy initiative from compostable serveware to reusables.',
  },
];
const renderItem = item => {
  const {
    renderOrderItem,
    bgImageStyle,
    headerTextStyle,
    discountValStyle,
    bodyTextStyle,
  } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={renderOrderItem}>
      <ImageBackground
        imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
        style={bgImageStyle}
        source={{ uri: item.bgImage }}
      >
        <Text style={headerTextStyle}>{item.headerText}</Text>
        <Text isSerif style={discountValStyle}>
          {item.discountVal}
        </Text>
        {/* <Text style={bodyTextStyle}>{item.bodyText}</Text> */}
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};
      <FlatList
        data={carData}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => renderItem(item)}
        keyExtractor={id => id.toString()}
      />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set fixed image size in style.

Comment: Give Fixed Height

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give `flex:1` to your imageBackground and resize mode of the image to `contain`.